# how to access in attribut APP.XAML.cs

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have class "APP.XAML.cs" and other class "list.xaml.cs" in the same project in class "APP.XAML.cs"I have attribute public static string ClientID {get; set;} in the "list.xaml.cs" I have method clientInformation public void clientInformation () {IDClient=App. ClientID;} in this ligne IDClient=App.ClientID; I have this error App "error CS0119: 'App' est un type, qui n'est pas valide dans le contexte donné"

```
 namespace Panels
    {//class App
        public partial class App : Application
        {
        public static string ClientID {get; set;}
         public App()
            {
                this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
                this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
                this.UnhandledException +=    
                this.Application_UnhandledException;
                InitializeComponent();            
            }
        }
     namespace Panels
    {//class list
        public partial class list : UserControl
        {
        public void clientInformation () { IDClient=App.ClientID; } 
       }

        }
```

Comment: please I need your help for this problem 'App' est un type, qui n'est pas valide dans le contexte donné"

Comment: You are gong to need to provide a [mcve]. The current state/format of the question does not allow for much help to be provided.

Answer (score 1):

you can Use This Sample:

```
((App)Application.Current).ClientID =1
```

Comment: change ==> public static string ClientID {get; set;} To==> public string ClientID {get; set;}